# PHP: show HTML comments

Tags: php, html, comments

Consider the following PHP function:

```php
function show_html_comment($comment)
{
   echo '<!-- ' . $comment . ' -->';
}
```

This function displays HTML comments.

But what if inside `$comment` there is an HTML comment?

```php
$comment = '<!-- foo -->';
```

The result of the function would be:

```
<!-- <!-- foo --> -->
```

And I do not want that. Nor should I show a modified version of the string (for example using htmlspecialchars()). I have to display the string as it is within an HTML comment.

Can anyone come up with a solution?

Comment: [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) for example: `echo '<!-- ' . htmlspecialchars($comment, ENT_QUOTES) . ' -->';`

Comment: I cannot display a modified string. So this solution comes to me: insert special characters. For example: --[SPECIAL CHAR HERE]> Thus the browser does not detect that it is an end of comment token. But I have to test it.

Comment: please show your "modified string" in updated question description

Comment: Another solution I can think of is to replace <!-- --> with [!-- --], or with similar Unicode characters, which might be an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) as @vee mention in the comment or instead if you are pretty sure about structure of your string you can use [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) like:

```
function show_html_comment($comment)
{
    $comment = str_replace('<!--', '', $comment);
    $comment = str_replace('-->', '', $comment);
    echo '<!-- ' . trim($comment) . ' -->';
}

show_html_comment('<!-- foo -->'); // <!--  foo  -->
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Simone, but I can't remove the comment start / end tokens.

Comment: @richirm then replace `<!` to `!` and `>` to empty. Or `<!-` to `[!-` and `->` to `-]` as you commented.

Answer (score 0):

I post here what I have investigated:

An initial solution could be to replace the < !-- and --> tokens with [!-- --] or {!-- --} or something similar.

Another possible solution is to insert blanks inside the tokens.

Another solution could be to replace some characters in the tokens with similar Unicode characters. For example, use the hyphen character U+2010 instead of the character U+002D, or replace the < > characters with similar ones. For example, you could put comments like:

< !-- ≺!-- ≺!-- foo --≻ --≻ -->

Here are the similar characters I have found so far:

```
‹ ›
≺ ≻
＜＞
```

Another solution could be to insert invisible characters inside the  tokens to "break the tokens" so that the browser does not detect them as HTML comments. It occurs to me to use for example the character U+200E.

For instance:

If you run the following code, you will have a file with an HTML comment inside another HTML comment, and the browser will not detect it:

```
file_put_contents('test.html', '<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><!-- <' . "\u{200e}" . '!-- foo --' . "\u{200e}" . '> --></body></html>');
```